# RangeError: Issue in flutter image compressing

Tags: android, ios, flutter, compression, flutter-dependencies

I am using the flutter plugin [flutter_image_compress](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image_compress)

below is the code

```
File compressImage(File file)  {
    // Get file path
    // eg:- "Volume/VM/abcd.jpeg"
    final filePath = file.absolute.path;
    
    // Create output file path
    // eg:- "Volume/VM/abcd_out.jpeg"
    final lastIndex = filePath.lastIndexOf(new RegExp(r'.jp'));
    final splitted = filePath.substring(0, (lastIndex));
    final outPath = "${splitted}_out${filePath.substring(lastIndex)}";

    File compressedFile;

    FlutterImageCompress.compressAndGetFile(
          filePath, 
          outPath,
          minWidth: 1000,
          minHeight: 1000,
          quality: 70).then((value) => compressedFile = value);

    return compressedFile;
}
```

This returns the following error

```
RangeError: Value not in range: -1
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is related to the string. You need to sure that your file name ends with .jpg or .jpeg, not with .png or something like this.

```
final filePath = file.absolute.path;

// Create output file path
// eg:- "Volume/VM/abcd_out.jpeg"
final lastIndex = filePath.lastIndexOf(new RegExp(r'.jp'));
final splitted = filePath.substring(0, (lastIndex));
final outPath = "${splitted}_out${filePath.substring(lastIndex)}";
```

Comment: Okay but this is not the answer definitely. User should be able to select whatever the image he want, not just jpg

Answer (score 0):

The issue is from the out path. It should end with ".jpeg" or ".jpg"

```
Directory path = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
var compressedImage = await FlutterImageCompress.compressAndGetFile(
   image.path,
    path.path + "${DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch}.jpeg",
    minWidth: 2300,
    minHeight: 1500,
    quality: 94,
  );
```